# :onI'm my prefix but my prefix is not necessarily me

Tags: riddle, affix-riddle

I'm my prefix,

But my prefix is not necessarily me.

My suffix determines

If you are dirty-minded.

When I appears,

One person will be really happy,

And one person will not.

What am I?

Hint:

> my last letter is the last letter of this sentence.

Hint:

> the rest of my suffix is the common prefix of two related software

Comment: "One people" is intended, by the way. (Although not significant.)

Comment: It is related to one of my interest by the way

Comment: Interest? Is that deliberate?

Comment: neccesarily->necessarily?

Comment: The intended answer is much less farfetched than peanut.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling, TwilightSparkle :) Just to be clear, do you mean "one people" as in "one nation/race/etc" or do you mean "one person" (singular)? Thanks.

Comment: @Stiv Thanks. See above, it is intended, but to prevent confusion, I'll edit that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another possibility:

> Checkmate

I'm my prefix, But my prefix is not necessarily me.

> In checkmate the king is in check but there is no way to protect him. In a normal check the king has a way to be protected

My suffix determines If you are dirty-minded.

> Mate selection?

When I appears, One person will be really happy, And one person will not.

> Winner/Loser

Hint 2:

> Matlab/Mathematica

Comment: Congrats!! You got it!~

Answer (score 4):

One possible answer is:

> **A SNOWBALL**

*I'm my prefix,*
*But my prefix is not necessarily me.*

> A snowball is made of **SNOW**; however, snow exists in many forms other than a snowball.

*My suffix determines*
*If you are dirty-minded.*

> Talk of a **BALL** to someone and there are multiple interpretations, some ruder than others (e.g. sports equipment vs body parts...).

*When I appears,*
*One person will be really happy,*
*And one person will not.*

> When somebody makes a **SNOWBALL** during a snowball fight, the person holding it is happy at the possibilities before them - their opponent suddenly is not, as they may be about to be hit with something cold, hard and painful!

Comment: *NB I began answering this question before the hint was added...*

Comment: Why do this puzzle have this many answers? :( A snowball is not "snow" though (Otherwise I could argue that a CPU is transistor, or you are quarks)

Comment: Now there's two answers I might as well add a second hint

Comment: @TwilightSparkle ^ The difference there though is that if you refer to a snowball as 'snow' nobody would think you are being pedantic (a snowball is indisputably snow, just shaped as a ball - the clue's in the name!) - whereas try to justify humans equating to nothing more than 'quarks' and you start off a full philosophical debate! ;-)

Comment: lolololololol without context you can't say a snowball "appeared" though